# webpack require fails if file path using string variable concat

Tags: webpack

I've been encountering strange webpack require problem. If I use variable in require string, it fails to load anything but no error message. But use full path string will succeed in loading. Do you know what is going on?

```
var _commonFolder = '../Presentation/Base/Default/js/source/_common/'
require(_commonFolder + 'docReady.js');
// the above require will fail to load anything, but no error message


require('../Presentation/Base/Default/js/source/_common/docReady.js');
// the above require successfully load the content
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, what you are try to do comes under dynamic requires of a file .

Read webpack documentation explaining [dynamic requires](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#dynamic-requires).

```
var _commonFolder = '../Presentation/Base/Default/js/source/_common/'
require(_commonFolder + 'docReady.js');
```

Here, **`docReady.js`** will not get bundled as require contains expression  `_commonFolder + 'docReady.js`and that can't be resolved by webpack while compiling and bundling .

On getting expression inside require like in your case , webpack may create a [context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#context-module) in your bundled output file.

whereas

```
require('../Presentation/Base/Default/js/source/_common/docReady.js');
```

will bundle **`docReady.js`** by webpack as you are providing complete relative path